# How do I ensure that animations work correctly across all views

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a standard way to have views that are de-activated have an animation which slides away or a view brought active to slide in?

I was thinking of having a base controller for the view port, and then an event 'activeitemchange' which sets the animation of the view coming in.  But when I inherit my controllers from the base controller I get the following error:

```
Failed loading 'http://localhost:1212/touch/src/app/AppController.js'
```

Not sure what the problem is, or even if this is the correct way of achieving this...?

Comment: What you need is an Ext.view.Navigation where you can push and pop views with animation or not.

Comment: And from your last three stories I would say you'd better think you app through and start with the right structure for your views.

Comment: Ok, but how do I achieve this? I can't find anything in the docs which allows me to set a standard animation on all views. I don't want to have to repeat this on each view (goes against DRY principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a navigation view where the animation is set only once in the navigation view's config.

http://www.senchafiddle.com/full/!izRlK/

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your patience! How do I see the code on the fiddle?

Comment: Open the Web Inspector/Firebug and look at the files app.js, View.js, Main.js and Navigation.js.